# How to execute the multiple java programs using pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am new to maven pom.xml

> there is nay way to execute the .java files using pom.xml If there is
>   any to do please send me.

this java file have the selenium code (Junit code)

Ex:

```
package com.mycompany.app; 

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*; 
import org.junit.BeforeClass; import org.junit.Test; import
org.testng.annotations.AfterClass; import
org.testng.annotations.AfterGroups; import
org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;

public class App4 {

    @Test
    public void Login1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("*******Love u mom*******");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) which is intended exactly for that purpose. You can use the [java](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal like this or may be you need the [exec](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <key>myproperty</key>
              <value>myvalue</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay and how to run the pom.xml
Right click on pom.xml window editor -->run as -->Maven test.
where we can find the out put of this pom.xml execution.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise please see the above mention code and tell the how to execute the pom.xml also

Comment: Now the picture has changed cause now we are talking about integration tests which is a complete different thing. You should take a deep look into maven-failsafe-plugin to execute integration tests. [Take a detailed and deep look here](http://khmarbaise.github.io/maui/it-example-container.html).

Answer (score 0):

For running Junit tests you can use the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). Simply add it to your pom:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By default it generates two reports in text and xml format under: `${basedir}/target/surefire-reports`.

By default it expects to find your tests under `src/test/java` (a maven convention). All tests found there will be executed.

Comment: Please tell me how to run the pom.xml

Comment: Run the pom? I guess you mean execute maven? From the command line you can simply enter `mvn test` and that will execute everything up to and including the test phase of the maven build [lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). If you're running within Eclipse, then right click on pom.xml window editor -->run as -->Maven test should work.